# Proof Verification: Continuity and Normed Linear Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm not sure if my proof is completely correct or if the logic is completely sound. Thank you.:

Question: 
Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are both normed linear spaces. Suppose that $f$ is continuous. Show that if X and Y are endowed with equivalent norms, then $f$ remains continuous.

Proof: We show the case where both X and Y have equivalent norms and the other case follows.
Suppose we have a normed linear space {$X$,$||||_{x_a}$}.  We say $||||_{x_b}$ and $||||_{x_a}$ are equivalent meaning: there exists constants $m$, $M$ so that:
$m$$||||_{x_a}\leq ||||_{x_b} \leq M||||_{x_a}$ Denote this as Equation 1.  Likewise suppose we have a normed linear space {$Y$,$||||_{y_a}$}. We say that $||||_{y_b}$ and $||||_{x_a}$ are equivalent with the same definition above.

Then, we have: $||f(x_1)-f(x_2)||_{y_b} \leq B||f(x_1)-f(x_2)||_{y_a}$ where $B$ is just a constant.
Moroever, since we assume that $f$ is continuous on:{$X$,$||||_{x_a}$} to {$Y$,$||||_{y_a}$}, we have by the definition of continuity that:
for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta$>0, such that:
$||f(x_1)-f(x_2)||_{y_a}< \epsilon/B$ , for $||(x_1)-(x_2)||_{x_a}< \delta$.
We have from equation 1, that:$||(x_1)-(x_2)||_{x_b} \leq M||(x_1)-(x_2)||_{x_a}$.
Thus for $\epsilon>0$, we have $||f(x_1)-f(x_2)||_{y_b} \leq \frac{B\epsilon}{B}$=$\epsilon$ when $||(x_1)-(x_2)||_{x_b}<\delta'$, where $\delta'=M\delta>0$.Thus, proving the result.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. if $f:X \to Y$ is given to be continuous, what is there to prove? Why would the fact that the norms are equivalent have to do with anything?

Comment: That it is still continuous if we endow X and Y with equivalent norms.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you replacing the norms on $X,Y$ by equivalent norms? What have these norms got to do with the original norms?

Comment: Yes say I have an a norm || ||x on X and a norm on Y || ||y for ex. We assume that the function is continuous from our normed space X to our normed space Y. We try to prove that if we have an equivalent norm || ||x1on X and || || y1 that the function from our normed space X to our normed space Y is still continuous.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a mistake in your last line. Rather than using $\Vert x_1 -x_2 \Vert_{x_b} \le M\Vert x_1-x_2 \Vert_{x_a}$, you would want to use the bound $\Vert x_1-x_2 \Vert_{x_a} \le \frac{1}{m}\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_b}$. This is because we want to bound $\Vert x_1-x_2 \Vert_{x_a}$ from above by some multiple of $\Vert x_1-x_2 \Vert_{x_b}$.

Thus given $x_1 \in X$ and $\varepsilon >0$, we can choose $\delta > 0$ such that $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_a} < \delta$ implies that $\Vert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\Vert_{y_a} < \frac{\varepsilon}{B}$. We can then set $\delta'=\delta m $, it then follows that

$$ \Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_b} < \delta' \Rightarrow \Vert x_1-x_2 \Vert_{x_a} \le \frac{1}{m}\Vert x_1-x_2 \Vert_{x_b}<\delta$$

This then implies that $\Vert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\Vert_{y_b} \le B\Vert f(x_1)-f(x_2) \Vert_{y_a}<\varepsilon$. Since the choice of $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary we have that $f$ is continuous at $x_1$. Since $x_1 \in X$ was also arbitrary we have that $f$ is continuous on all of $X$.

One more comment about your proof. It is not true that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$, $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_a}<\delta$ implies that $\Vert f(x_1)-f(x_2) \Vert_{y_a} < \frac{\varepsilon}{B}$. This would only be true if $f$ was uniformly continuous, since $f$ is only continuous you must first be given $x_1\in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ and then you can find a suitable $\delta > 0$.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much @michaelhowes.  So for my proof I would need say that given $x_1$ and $\epsilon>0$  we have etc.. as we just have continuity and not uniform continuity.  The reason I have:$\Vert x_1 -x_2 \Vert_{x_b} \le M\Vert x_1-x_2 \Vert_{x_a}$ is because the continuity holds from  $x_a$ to $y_a$ as I described when ||x1-x2||x_a<delta.  Thus, it holds when ||x1-x2||x_b<M||x1-x2||x_a<Mdelta.  I'm not exactly sure why this would be incorrect.  Thanks.

Comment: @kemb The problem with the bound $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_b} \le M\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_a}$ is because we want to show that $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_b} < \delta'$ implies that $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_b} < \delta$. Just having that $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_b} < M\delta$ does not imply that $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_a} < \delta$. All we have that is $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_b} < M\delta$ and $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_b} \le M\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_a}$. It is still possible that $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert_{x_a} \ge \delta$ which is not what we want.

Comment: I see thank you.  Is everything else fine?

Comment: I think you might have a typo in the first paragraph of the proof. The last $x_a$ should be a $y_a$. Apart from that, it looks good to me.